# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. (This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies)

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

**I haven't done any changes in any file all of a sudden when i try to start mysql from XAMPP i get the following error.**

```
21:14:28  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
21:14:28  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:14:28  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:14:28  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:14:28  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:14:28  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
21:14:28  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

**And the content of mysql_error.log**

```
   InnoDB: using atomic writes.
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 48087; transaction id 9
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2020-08-10 21:20:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200810 21:20:33
    2020-08-10 21:20:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2020-08-10 21:20:34 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I tried **changing the port** that didn't work, tried many other solutions nothing worked
I know a lot of forums have already discussed this issue, I tried many solutions none worked for me,
then at last had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the server port from 80 to another number, e.g 8888. It's possible another software is using port 80

Comment: did u mean apache main port?
if yes then tried it didn't work

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I don't use xampp now. I use laragon. It's way better. Try restarting the pc. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: No problem man, 
i tried everything that I could find,
had to reinstall at last